# Is there a way to clear a "consumes = MediaType" in Spring Boot RestController?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Let's say I have a controller that has a variety of endpoints (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) and generally they both produce and consume JSON, so I do:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value=["/some/base/path"], produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE], consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE])
public class SomeController {
    ...
}
```

But it turns out that my `@GetMapping` does not consume JSON (and I don't want to force callers to set `Content-Type: application/json` for `GET` requests. Is there a way, on the `@GetMapping`, to clear/empty the `consumes =` value that was set at the class level? Or is there another way to avoid repeating the `consumes` attribute on all methods in the class?

I've already tried setting the `@GetMapping(value=["/some/path"], consumes = [])` without any luck. For context, I'm converting from Jersey annotations to Spring REST controller style annotations and I'm finding this to be an annoying difference in behavior (setting a class-level `@Consumes` annotation doesn't get enforced against `@GET`s). And just looking for an elegant way to mirror existing behavior without cloning the consumes attribute all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your problem now .Try use the below solution and refer to this link that might help

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/1257/commits/00e6ca412dffeb8a7a596f9312db19eb6cc49525

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/get", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case , you need to delete the consumes part.I mean just use the Produces only.For example :

```
 @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/{oid}")
    public Book getBook(@PathParam("oid") String oid) {
        return bookService.getBook(oid);
    }
```

or check this url :
https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-building-restful-web-services-with-jersey

Comment: so, I already had Jersey mappings, and Im switching to spring rest controller mappings. And, I need to maintain the behavior of the existing API in this process, so I can't just remove produces/consumes behaviors, nor can the API become more strict in how it enforces produces/consumes.

Comment: @Kevin i got your problem ,i posted another answer i think it should work .